# Am I making my One-Time Passcode less secure?

Tags: random, one-time-password

I am using some "magic link" one-time passcodes for automatically logging users in for a specific purpose on our website.

My plan is to generate a hash based on the datetime, users specific "ID" and a random int.

Then take this hash and use it a prefix to uniqid as per:

```
$hash = sha1(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . $memberId . random_int(0, 9999) );
$OTP = uniqid($hash, true);
```

After a bit of thinking I guess the use of uniqid is pretty redundant, but would it actually make it ***less*** secure to do it this way?

Comment: I edited your title to clarify the distinction between One-Time Passcodes and One-Time Pad. Please don't be afraid to spell things out if there is a potential to mistake things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you take a hash of data containing in part random values, you would be better served by using directly random data, with the [random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) function.

For the usage of [uniqid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), you should first read its documentation. You are not using the "prefix" argument as it is meant to be used.

To directly answer your question, you should avoid using *uniqid* because it is not meant to be used to authenticate users. You could instead use a 16 bytes string returned by *random_bytes*, encoded in hexadecimal or base64.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your time - I will do exactly that.